# Combination of two fields as a unique key in all_subscriber list

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, subscriber-key

we have a subscriber key as a unique key in the all subscriber list. I want the combination of the two fields as the unique field in the all_subscribers list.
Say (SubscribeKey + EmailAddress) as a unique key in all_subscribers List.

Scenario:- I have two contact details are as follow:-
which have all the details same , even the subscriber key. only the emailaddress field is diiferent.

```
       FirstName:- James
       LastName:- Johan
       EmailAddress:- james.johan@gmail.com
       Subscriberkey:- 1234

       FirstName:- James
       LastName:- Johan
       EmailAddress:- james.johan@outlook.com
       Subscriberkey:- 1234
```

In this case, I want to create two different records in all_subscribers list with the same subscriber key. this is only possible when we have a combination of the two fields i.e(SubscribeKey + EmailAddress) as a unique key in all subscriber List.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You can't change the behaviour of All Subscribers - as it will always choose SubscriberKey as primary key.

Comment: is there any other way to execute this functionality.?

Comment: Please update your question to explain what you ultimately are attempting, as I suspect we are dealing with an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The question is WHY do you want to have this unique contraint of 2 fields instead of the primary key. What is the reasoning behind it. What do you want to ACHIEVE with it. As Lukas told -> Focus on the use case and the problem ... not a scenario you want to achieve, where we do not know what you want to achieve. Btw. like lukas said, you cannot change the allsubscriber to a two field unique constraint so we have to come up with a workaround. Please include the use case

Answer (score -3):

The all_subscribers list simply holds what you import or what ends up there through other means - single email, journey builder emails etc. You can't change its structure.

The subscriber key on that list will be populated with the value you choose to use as the SubscriberKey in your sends. This means that if you want to have the combination of the two, you will need to create that field in your sending lists (Data extensions) or Salesforce objects (if you're using the CRM) and perhaps even utilize SQL queries and Contact Builder to achieve what you want.

e.g. in a scenario where you're using Data Extensions, simply create a new sending Data Extension (via a SQL query) where you marry the SubscriberKey field and the email field into a new ID and chose to use that ID in your sends.

Comment: Cannot be an answer, because no question has actually been asked. And marrying ID with the email seems horrible - it may explode the number of contactacts you have licensed. And it really seems a bad idea which you should not follow